# C# parse one json field to an object with its custom constructor

Tags: c#, json, parsing, constructor

Let's assume I have a JSON string which looks something like this:

```
{
 "a" : "1",
 "b" : "string",
 "c" : ["1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00 Text1. Text2.",
        "1993-12-03T08:15:30-05:00 Text1b. Text2b."]
}
```

I want to parse it to:

```
class A
{
  int a;
  string b;
  List<CustomObjects> c;
}

class CustomObject
{
  DateTime date;
  string text1;
  string text2;
  void CustomObject(string constructString)
  {
    // parsing constructString into object fields
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can use some C# JSON parser like JSON.NET and provide CustomObject constructor to parse it the way I want?
I'm just trying to avoid writing my own parser. Maybe it's not necessary.

Comment: Serialize it as the object it actually is, then do your string parsing after the fact.  Its _ok_ to have multiple classes

Comment: Yeah, that's obvious solution. But I'm wondering whether its possible to do such thing in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible to do with Json.Net, without any changes to your JSON, using a small custom `JsonConverter` to tell it how to call your constructor:

```
class ConstructFromStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ConstructorInfo ctor = objectType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        if (ctor != null)
        {
            return ctor.Invoke(new object[] { (string)reader.Value });
        }
        throw new JsonException(objectType.Name + " does not have a public constructor that accepts a string.");
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To use the converter with your `CustomObject` class, you just need to put a `[JsonConverter]` attribute on it like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ConstructFromStringConverter))]
class CustomObject
{
    ...
}
```

Then, you can deserialize your JSON in the usual way and it will "just work":

```
A a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json);
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/md2hH6

Comment: Thanks. That's great.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonConstructor` attribute if you modify your json like this:

```
{  
   "a":"1",
   "b":"string",
   "c":[  
      {  
         "constructString":"1994 -11-05T08:15:30-05:00 Text1. Text2."
      },
      {  
         "constructString":"1993-12-03T08:15:30-05:00 Text1b. Text2b."
      }
   ]
}
```

then constructor of CustomObject will look like:

```
 [JsonConstructor]
 CustomObject(string constructString)
 {
    // parsing constructString into object fields
 }
```

parsing:

```
var aObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json);
```